# Image rotation using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to rotate an image through canvas and through the cropper.js library I can do the rotation of the image but save the image and condition it with canvas does not save me with the format of the rotation.

In my code what I have is an event that makes me rotating towards 90 or -90 degrees. Then when saving the image I need to be saved with that format.
I need to rotate on the axis of the image so that when the image is saved with rotate canvas it is saved with the correct position. I have seen some ways to do it but it has not worked for me, I do not know that I am losing.

```
    //Events to rotate using cropper Js library



          'click #rotateL': function(e, instance){
              $('#target').cropper('rotate', -90);
              angleInDegrees   = angleInDegrees - 90 ;
              drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
            },
            'click #rotateR': function(events, instance){
              $('#target').cropper('rotate', 90);
               angleInDegrees += 90;
               drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
            },

        function drawRotated(degrees){
        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var image = document.createElement("img");
         image.src = $('#target').attr("src");
        image.onload = function ()    {
         context.drawImage(image,(canvas.width - x1) / 2, 
          (canvas.height - y1) / 2,x1, y1);
         //ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height)
         }
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        context.save();
        context.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
        context.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
        context.drawImage(image, -x1/2,-y1/2);
        context.restore();
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        Session.set("url", dataURL);
}


// event that saves the changes made when you cut the image or rotate.
'click #Save' : function(e) {
    $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    var photoid = $('#photoid').val();
    var dataURL = Session.get("url");
       var photo =  {
                srcData : dataURL,
                userid : Meteor.userId(),
                photo_id : photoid
        }

        Meteor.call('updatePhoto',photo,function(err)  {
          if (!err) {
             $('#photos').show();
             $('#crops').hide();
              canvas.height = 0;
              canvas.width = 0;
             //page relod is better than
               //document.getElementById('target').src="";
             FlowRouter.go('/search');
             FlowRouter.go('/addphoto');
        }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cropper.js. You can use build-in method `getCroppedCanvas` to get edited and cropped new canvas back. There is no bother to write on your own.

```
var canvas = $ ('# target').cropper ('getCroppedCanvas');
console.log (canvas)
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL ("image / jpeg");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying the same does not work the problem lies in the translation I am now guiding by this example but only managed to get a portion of the image that does not match.
  update now using that example and nothing that works.
Http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/84/

Comment: Are you saying your problem is can't get image rotate in the right position. how about this http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/3203/ . The basic idea is how much value you translate to image center to do the rotate, there will be the same value you have to move it back.

Comment: If you look at the video so I leave the following link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4pYg956DHc4a1ZGNzBQcEpyMnc/view?usp=sharing so you understand a little better. The rotation I do with cropper.js equal the cut of the image as seen in the bear. Now to keep that rotation is where I have the problem to make canvas interpret that image was rotated and take those cutting marshes.

Comment: i see. since you are using cropper.js, did you try the function `cropper.getCroppedCanvas();` to get cropped image?

Comment: no i am using ``angleInDegrees = $('#imgrotate').val(); ``

Comment: Honestly it's hard to help. If you can made it into a simple working example on jsfiddle, I think it will be easier for us to spot your problem.

Comment: Assuming that here I get all the data from crop `var canvasData = $ ('# target'). Cropper ('getCanvasData');` As I would give the var dataURL = `canvas.toDataURL ("image / jpeg");` I take that data? I would have to use context.drawImage (img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height); To understand a little to what you talk about that part, take it to the jsfidlle is a little complicated working with meteor not js pure.

Comment: Thanks for the help I needed getCroppedCanvas and there if I could assign to my dataUrl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149641/discussion-between-monkianer-and-marcelrama).

Answer (score 1):

To rotate 90 deg clockwise on a new canvas.

```
// assuming that image is a loaded image.
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = image.height;
canvas.height = image.width;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.setTransform(
    0,1,          // x axis down the screen
    -1,0,         // y axis across the screen from right to left
    image.height, // x origin is on the right side of the canvas 
    0             // y origin is at the top
);
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

To rotate -90Deg onto a new canvas

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = image.height;
canvas.height = image.width;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.setTransform(
    0,-1,       // x axis up the screen
    1,0,        // y axis across the screen from left to right
    0,          // x origin is on the left side of the canvas 
    image.width // y origin is at the bottom
);
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

The origins are where the top left corner of the image ends up being after the rotation.

Comment: Hi @blindman67, thanks for responding I tried to perform as you indicated but I did not do anything that made it work in the video, you can see how it works when I rotate 90 -90 and 180 .https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4pYg956DHc4a1ZGNzBQcEpyMnc